# Databases, Relational algebra, constraint/dependencies

Tags: sql, database

I have the following:

[image]

I'm trying to recap a lecture and I don't really understands what going on.

1) So, PropertyID is a key  therefore PropertyID (arrow) Area
2) County_ name and Lot# make a key therefore Countyname,Cot# (arrow) PropertyID,area
3) This is where I get confused, my professor goes onto say that FD5 isn't a candidate key but if it were to be combined with e.g. LOT# it could then be done as a candidate key and then Lot#,area (arrow) County_name would be valid. Could anyone explain the reasoning for Area not being a valid key on it's own?

if anyone can help me out, be appreciated.

Comment: Keys need to be unique. Perhaps area combined with others will be unique hence it could be a key.